# How to store strings and then search for them using substrings efficiently?

Tags: string, algorithm, search, data-structures

I want and idea to store strings in a data structure and search for it knowing that the search algorithm will give me that string even though given input isn't a word.

For example:

Stored string in ds: "Data structures!"
Input: "ta"
Output: "Da**ta** structures!"

I can do it just by simply storing them in 1D array then with linear search find particular strings but it won't be efficient.

Comment: are the search strings that match always prefix/suffix of a word? Or would `ruc` in your example return `structures!`?

Comment: Any restriction how long the input might be?

Comment: Very wide theme. Start from suffix array.

Comment: @mrsmith42 it can be anything, there is no extra restrictions

Comment: @user1984 if the string was just "strucrures!", in this case the whole string - "Data structures!"

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the answer to my question. When we have "Data structures", and someone searches "ruc", should we match or not? In other words, must the query strings be prefix/suffix of words in the string, or can the be anywhere in the string.

Comment: @user1984 it can be anywhere in the string